# Zsh: condition if/then in prompt

Tags: zsh

Doc: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

doesn't seem to work in this use case.

Use case: if prompt contains `localhost` then remove hostname from prompt, if not prompt contains hostname like:

`(check %m contains 'localhost' then result empty, if not the use %m in prompt)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%m` expands to the value of `$HOST` (initialised at startup from the host name).

So you could use:

```
set -o promptsubst
PS1='${HOST##*localhost*}'
```

Or, as `$HOST` would typically not change (not even when the host name changes), and assuming it doesn't contain `%` characters:

```
PS1="${HOST##*localhost*}"
```

(expand it in your `~/.zshrc`).

Comment: I need it in `%m` instead of expand t `$HOST`, I use `PROMPT=` in zshrc, and somehow the expaned doesn't effect.

Comment: Even though, I end up with some if/then to set PROMPT. Thanks.

Comment: @TuyenPham `PS1` is the same as `PROMPT` (one is from Bourne sh, one from csh,). `%m` is the same as `$HOST`. For expansions to be done in the prompts, you need the `promptsubst` option.

Comment: Thanks, I tested your setup again using `print -P '${HOST##*localhost*}'`and I've noticed that If I remove one or more of `ocalhos`, reuslt is print out `localhost` and is expected. But if I remove `l` of `lo` or `t` of `st`, result print out empty - means same result as whole word `localhost`. How it can be fixed? Why I can't tag you?

Comment: @TuyenPham, I don't understand what you mean `${HOST##*localhost*}` is meant to expand to the empty string if `$HOST` contains `localhost` and to `$HOST` otherwise as requested. There's no "tag" completion offered for me as I'm the author of the article you're commenting on so I'm always notified anyway.

Comment: Mean I want to test the case that my hostname is currently `localhost` then `print -P` and modify `${HOST##*localhost*}` to `${HOST##*ocalhost*}` show empty in result, this is not expected, it should print `localhost` as normal because the matching patern here is `ocalhost`.

Comment: @TuyenPham `${HOST##*ocalhost*}` expands to the empty string if `$HOST` contains `ocalhost` and to `$HOST` otherwise, if you want to test `${HOST##*localhost*}` for different values of `$HOST`, just test after `HOST=localhost` or `HOST=something-else`...

Comment: Probably we both forget to put `PROMPT` in `precmd_functions`. Thanks.

Comment: @TuyenPham, not sure what you mean, `$PROMPT` in `zsh` is the primary prompt (an alias for `PS1` for compatibility with `tcsh`), `precmd_functions` are functions executed before each prompt is displayed. You don't need to set `$PROMPT` there, you'd typically assign a fixed value to `$PROMPT` (or preferably `$PS1`) in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: True, Idk why I'm just so confused.